# Difference between two ways of type casting List to List<T>

Tags: java, java-8

```
public static <T> List<T> templatizeList(final List list, final Class<T> clazz) {
        return (List<T>) list;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> typeSafeAdd(List<?> from, Class<T> clazz) {
        List<T> to = new ArrayList<>();
        from.forEach(item -> to.add(clazz.cast(item)));
        return to;
    }
```

What is the difference between the two methods? Is one way safer or faster than the other or it does not matter?

Comment: One returns a new list while the other one returns the same.

Comment: @Tunaki yes, but, which one is better to use or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Why are you using raw types to begin with? But define "better"

Comment: Hibernate returns raw list when queried upon 
`public List find(final String queryString, final Object... values) throws DataAccessException {.. return queryObject.list()}`

Comment: You must be using a _very_ old Hibernate version. It depends what you want to do: return a new list or not. There's no "better".

Comment: By better, I meant recommended way of doing it. I am using spring-orm-3.2.13.RELEASE version

Comment: Neither of them is safe. You're completely ignoring the type of values in the source list.

Comment: Both approaches are fundamentally unsafe. The recommended way of doing it is, therefore, don't. If you absolutely _need_ to do this, then I think @Darshan Mehta's answer makes a good point.

Answer (score 6):

As per Java docs, generics are limited to compile time. They go away once the code compiles, this is called [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Now, regarding the methods, method 1 just adds a cast to the list without checking the type of all the elements present into it. Meaning, you may get an unexpected ClasscastException anywhere in code at runtime if the List is cast to Cat type and what comes out of it is a Dog.

Method 2 creates an entirely new list, it iterates through all the elements and tries to cast each element in target type. Meaning, it would fail if all the elements can't be cast to the target type.

I would say method 2 is safe as it makes sure everything is fine before adding a cast (i.e. localizes the risk). Method 1 may allow List (which contains Cat, Dog, Dinosaur) to be cast to List< Cat > and then, you may get unexpected failures.

[This example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) explains it well.

Comment: Stated a bit more strongly than warranted. Method 2 is not safe, but it does localize the risk. That's as good as it gets, I think.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to say. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Given the discussion, I'd like to suggest an option that combines the best of both worlds: it both localizes the risk of an unsafe cast *AND* it avoids creating a new List. And it's easy. (I'm making this community wiki since I'm just borrowing others' ideas.)

*Step 1:* Do the cast for each element from Method 2. Don't do anything with the result, just do the cast. That will ensure that a bad value will be caught right upfront.

*Step 2:* Do the `List` cast from Method 1.

## Yet another idea

If you *know* that the `List` you got from Hibernate contains only the right type of element, then you can go ahead with Method 1. (The Eclipse JDT (at least prior to Mars) does the same thing in the AST. I have to deal with raw types far more often than I'd like.)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first one you return the same list, while the second creates a new list.

I dont think there's  a 'safer' of the two- since it eventually cast all list objecta on both, a non T object will cause classCastException on both.

The first is better in my mind- not creating a rather redundant new list

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine whether the List really should have the generic parameters . You must know beforehand what the parameters should be (or you'll find out when you get a ClassCastException). This is why the code generates a warning, because the compiler can't possibly know whether it is safe.

If you want to support more generic data type,
then you can go with

```
public static <T> List<?> templatizeList(final List list, final Class<T> clazz) {
    return (List<?>) list;
}
```

Otherwise,
2nd option makes sure that it is always of same type but it creates new List object...

So if you are sure then use either your 1st solution or my first option otherwise your second solution is decent removing the part it is creating new object.